# iPod "Classic" 60 GB and Bose SoundDock

Tags: ipod

I have an old "classic" 60GB iPod that I have been using with a Bose SoundDock for years. All of the sudden, one day, there is no sound coming from the dock speakers.  I can listen to the Ipod with headphones and when I place the Ipod on the dock it charges, but no sound.  I have tried replacing the board on the dock, but that didn't help.  Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have any other iPods (or iPhones) you can test with that dock? Or any other docks you can use with that iPod? If you could test this, this would determine whether it is the dock or the iPod that is the problem. I would also recommend contacting Bose support. Perhaps they might have some suggestions for things to try also.

Comment: I do not have any other ipods or docks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, without having access to another dock, or iPod, your options are somewhat limited, as there could be a number of things that failed. Because without another dock, or iPod, either the dock, or the iPod could be at fault. With that in mind, your best options are probably to take the iPod to an Apple store (schedule and appointment) and see if they can offer assistance in testing to see if your iPod had a hardware failure.

If the Apple store can't find anything wrong with it, then it may be time to send your Bose SoundDock into Bose to see about repair.